# Python: monkey patch a function's source code

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, monkeypatching

Can I add a prefix and suffix to the source code of functions?

I know about decorators and do not want to use them (the minimal example below doesn't make clear why, but I have my reasons).

```
def f():
    print('world')
g = patched(f,prefix='print("Hello, ");',suffix='print("!");')
g() # Hello, world!
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import inspect
import ast
import copy
def patched(f,prefix,suffix):
    source = inspect.getsource(f)
    tree = ast.parse(source)
    new_body = [
        ast.parse(prefix).body[0],
        *tree.body[0].body,
        ast.parse(suffix).body[0]
    ]
    tree.body[0].body = new_body
    g = copy.deepcopy(f)
    g.__code__ = compile(tree,g.__code__.co_filename,'exec')
    return g
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens if I use this and then call `g()` as above; neither `world` nor `Hello, world!` are printed.

Comment: Is it important, that you change the source of the function `f`, e.g. use local variables from f in suffix?

Comment: You can use `dis` to explore he compiled code of the changed function -- this should shed light on what's happening.

Comment: What is `print(inspect.getsource(g))`?

Comment: @Daniel yes, for example I want to add 'return locals()' to the end of the function

Comment: But if there is `return` in your function `f`, that won't work.

Comment: @Daniel that's not true. It will work, my added return statement will just not be executed. That's the desired behavior

Comment: @snakecharmerb I found an answer based on this hint (for everyone else: the `g` in my question was a module), but I still don't understand the output of `print(inspect.getsource(g))` in case you want to have a look at my answer and help improve it

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Dynamically patching the source code is more complicated than it seems on first sight.

Comment: @daniel appreciate your attempt to save me from myself but the journey is the destination here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rough version of what can be done:

```
import inspect
import ast
import copy
def patched(f,prefix,suffix):
    source = inspect.getsource(f)
    tree = ast.parse(source)
    new_body = [
        ast.parse(prefix).body[0],
        *tree.body[0].body,
        ast.parse(suffix).body[0]
    ]
    tree.body[0].body = new_body
    code = compile(tree,filename=f.__code__.co_filename,mode='exec')
    namespace = {}
    exec(code,namespace)
    g = namespace[f.__name__]
    return g

def temp():
    pass
def f():
    print('world',end='')
g = patched(f,prefix='print("Hello, ",end="")',suffix='print("!",end="")')
g() # Hello, world!
```

The call of `compile` compiles an entire module (represented by `tree`). This module is then executed in an empty namespace from which the desired function is finally extracted. (Warning: the namespace will need to be filled with some globals from where `f` comes from if `f` uses those.)

---

After some more work, here is a real example of what can be done with this. It uses some extended version of the principle above:

```
import numpy as np
from playground import graphexecute
@graphexecute(verbose=True)
def my_algorithm(x,y,z):
    def SumFirstArguments(x,y)->sumxy:
        sumxy = x+y
    def SinOfThird(z)->sinz:
        sinz = np.sin(z)
    def FinalProduct(sumxy,sinz)->prod:
        prod = sumxy*sinz
    def Return(prod):
        return prod
print(my_algorithm(x=1,y=2,z=3)) 
#OUTPUT:
#>>Executing part SumFirstArguments
#>>Executing part SinOfThird
#>>Executing part FinalProduct
#>>Executing part Return
#>>0.4233600241796016
```

The clou is that I get the exact same output if I reshuffle the parts of `my_algorithm`, for example like this:

```
@graphexecute(verbose=True)
def my_algorithm2(x,y,z):
    def FinalProduct(sumxy,sinz)->prod:
        prod = sumxy*sinz
    def SumFirstArguments(x,y)->sumxy:
        sumxy = x+y
    def SinOfThird(z)->sinz:
        sinz = np.sin(z)
    def Return(prod):
        return prod
print(my_algorithm2(x=1,y=2,z=3)) 
#OUTPUT:
#>>Executing part SumFirstArguments
#>>Executing part SinOfThird
#>>Executing part FinalProduct
#>>Executing part Return
#>>0.4233600241796016
```

This works by (1) grabbing the source of `my_algorithm` and turning it into an ast (2) patching each function defined within `my_algorithm` (e.g. SumFirstArguments) to return locals (3) deciding based on the inputs and the outputs (as defined by the type hints) in which order the parts of `my_algorithm` should be executed. Furthermore, a possibility that I do not have implemented yet is to execute independent parts in parallel (such as `SumFirstArguments` and `SinOfThird`). Let me know if you want the sourcecode of `graphexecute`, I haven't included it here because it contains a lot of stuff that is not relevant to this question.

Comment: "feel like it could be done better" Mainly with a decorator. This is exactly why they were invented. I'm not sure why one would impose such a general (almost arbitrary) restriction on themselves (which is almost like "I don't want to use functions, I have my reasons")

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm playing around and hope to learn. I'm not using this to land a rocket on the moon. Somehow pythonistas always criticize your motives; ask a similar question about C and you'll learn dozen ways to achieve what you asked in the most obscure ways possible ;)

Comment: @deepspace also I don't think something like an added 'return locals()' at the  end of a function could be handled with decorators

Comment: highly doubt that C would allow you to inject code into existing code.  it’s nice that you are trying out stuff, and yes, there’s a lot of whydothisitis around, but yours is still very much an edge case so no need to criticize, esp if someone doesn’t know your skill level and might be just trying to keep you from wasting time

Comment: @Bananach: you have a wrong idea, of what decorators do.

Comment: Your traceback is messed up, because you don't have the source code of your modified function. Also, the globals are not the same in your newly compiled function.

Comment: @JLpeyret a similar question would be how to do X in C this without pointers, without the heap, without recursion, without functions, ... I might have been to snappy though

Comment: @Daniel why do I have a wrong idea? I understand they are syntactic sugar for higher order functions and don't get to see the inner workings of their argument, that is, the function to be modified. As such they cannot modify that function to return all of its local variables

Comment: no worries. you are right sometimes you explicitly say “i want to do this” and people still insist on “correcting” you. is your use case specifically gaining insight on the internals of a called function, such as seeing its locals?  so you don’t get what you want from viewing/altering only its parameters and output?  do you control the function yourself?  ie is it your code that you want to dynamically view?  might use some hacky conditionals to do that, i guess.

Comment: C culture vs Python culture is an interesting question.  I'd guess - based on a purely python perspective - that the constraints that C programs have historically operated under, such as low memory and/or embedded systems, real-time etc,  place a premium on exploring inventive solutions, even at the cost of readability.  Whereas Python programs tend not to operate in such constrained environments, so the culture values readability and is more inclined to say "just because you can doesn't mean you should".  Just pondering ...

Comment: @JLPeyret it is my own code and I'm basically trying to write as little repetitive code as possible in a bunch of functions that do similar things but in a very different way (think different sort algorithms)

Comment: well you can do stuff like grabbing a locals() from a function and then passing to another function. i do this with Django views.  first i query a db to get all sorts of resultsets back, using a common naming convention.  then i instantiate a particular backend management class and pass in the locals.  i decorate the function to set attributes on the function specifying which class to instantiate and things like the django template path to use. finanny the manager renders the http response. sure, it’s complex but it reduced code duplication tremendously.  still not monkeypatching.

Comment: @JLPeyret see the updated answer for what I can do with the monkeypatching

Comment: @DeepSpace see the updated answer for what I can do with the monkeypatching

Comment: @Daniel see the updated answer for what I can do with the monkeypatching

Comment: @Bananach could you share the source code of graphexecute? I'm quite interested in what it does.

Comment: @Danny https://github.com/soerenwolfers/swutil/blob/master/swutil/future.py

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, you don't need to recompile your functions. Just define a list of functions, you inspect for arguments and return variable name:

```
def FinalProduct(sumxy, sinz) -> "prod":
    return sumxy * sinz

def SumFirstArguments(x, y) -> "sumxy":
    return x + y

def SinOfThird(z) -> "sinz":
    return np.sin(z)

def execute(funcs, **args):
    result = None
    while funcs:
        func = funcs.pop(0)
        try:
            kw = {a: args[a]
                for a in func.__code__.co_varnames[:func.__code__.co_argcount]
            }
        except KeyError:
            # not all arguments found
            funcs.append(func)
        else:
            print(func,kw)
            result = func(**kw)
            args[func.__annotations__['return']] = result
    return result

print(execute([FinalProduct, SumFirstArguments, SinOfThird], x=1,y=2,z=3))
```

Comment: +1 for not giving up on me. But what if one of the functions changes x (eg through x+=1) and I want to use that changed value of x in the others? I could add x to the outputs then, but since I cant prevent a function that sees x from changing it, it might be best to always assume that inputs are changed. Furthermore, the fact that I don't enforce return statements allows me to let the user decide when the algorithm is done. Anyway, in a serious environment your solution would definitely win for the simplicity and cleanliness :)